Can I plug a 3.5in SATA HDD into a port that supports 2.5in SATA HDD?
I am attempting to purchase a SATA Drive for my Olimex Lime 2. I know that the device itself supports 2.5" SATA with 5v of power.
Can I plug a 3.5" HDD into the SATA port? If the SATA drive requires more than the 5v standard for 2.5" HDD, can I utilize an external power source?

A useful thing here is - is the connector for the olimex lime data and power in one or split? Your options can depend there

Pretty much.
As you surmised the 2.5" and 3.5" data interface is the same so this is doable - the differences between 2.5" drives are the size of the drive and the power requirements - a 5v power supply that can support a 2.5" drive almost certainly won't drive a 3.5" drive.  Importantly, a 3.5" drive will normally require 12 volts and 5 volts - so you will need to hack around with that (and make sure the grounding is common).

One of the 'nice' things about Bitcoin and Chia is - well the preponderance of 'strange' adaptors.
The SATA power and data ports are physically the same, but this is meant for using laptop drives in desktops. Data's the same for both, power's the issue, and you can power the hard drive separately. I'm less sure that they need 'common' grounds as davidgo's suggested since I've seen setups with multiple ATX PSUs powering hard drives for the same machine.
Depending on your needs - you could probably get away with a 'simple' 12v female barrel plug to sata adaptor (AliExpress calls them DC 5525 to SATA and they have a little box in the middle to do voltage conversion) or dedicated 12v bricks with sata power supplies. There's also dedicated PSUs for this sort of thing, even ones 'triggered' by other PSUs. There's a ton of options.
I also suspect in this case, you might be able to get sufficient 5v with the right adaptors and use the hard drive power supply to power the Olimex Lime 2, which might be a neater solution.

The SATA port on the Olimex Lime is ONLY the DATA connection, which is technically identical as the data connection for a 3.5" drive.
No problem there, but...
The 5V power-feed intended for the 2.5" SATA-drive is most likely not powerful enough to drive a 3.5" drive (and most 3.5" drives need +12V as well).
So you will need to provide a separate power-feed (+5 and +12V) to the 3.5" inch drive and make sure that has a common ground with the ground of the Olimex board's power-feed. (Note that the GND line in the SATA data-connector itself, is NOT a common ground for the power-feed. It is signal ground only.)
